# Detect Marker Position in 2D image

Tags: java, image-processing, 2d

I am using Java as programming language to fix a problem I am facing at the moment.

I need to know the position (x,y) of the markers on the following image.

[image]

Is that already been done with some java library I guess no?

The markers are the little black squares.

Thank you so much in advance for your help

Comment: opencv has java bindings - http://opencv.org/

Comment: which tutorial should I look into on OpenCV to accomplish this problem?

Comment: maybe this one http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html ?

Answer (score -1):

I think chaper two of the book [Mastering OpenCV with Practical Computer Vision Projects](http://image2measure.net/files/Mastering_OpenCV.pdf) would be a good starting point.