# OpenCV - C++ to Java - Template Match

Tags: java, c++, templates, opencv, match

I am trying to detect more than a square (marker) in my image as I ask here [Detect Marker Position in 2D image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746951/detect-marker-position-in-2d-image)

There is one guy that showed me a solution in C++, here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


//See: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html
//See: http://answers.opencv.org/question/60382/detect-markers-position-in-2d-images/
int main() {
  cv::Mat img, templateImg, result;
  cv::VideoCapture capture("http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14297307634571599.png");
  if(capture.isOpened()) {
    capture >> img;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }

  capture = cv::VideoCapture("http://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/14297308125543022.png");
  if(capture.isOpened()) {
    capture >> templateImg;
  } else {
    return -1;
  }

  /// Reduce the size of the image to display it on my screen
  cv::resize(img, img, cv::Size(), 0.5, 0.5);
  /// Reduce the size of the template image
  /// (first to fit the size used to create the image test, second to fit the size of the reduced image)
  cv::resize(templateImg, templateImg, cv::Size(), 0.25, 0.25);

  cv::Mat img_display;
  img.copyTo(img_display);

  // Create the result matrix
  int result_cols =  img.cols - templateImg.cols + 1;
  int result_rows = img.rows - templateImg.rows + 1;

  result.create(result_rows, result_cols, CV_32FC1);

  /// Do the Matching and Normalize
  cv::matchTemplate(img, templateImg, result, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);
  cv::normalize(result, result, 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX, -1, cv::Mat());

  /// Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
  double minVal; double maxVal; cv::Point minLoc; cv::Point maxLoc;
  cv::Point matchLoc;

  for(;;) {
    cv::minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, cv::Mat());
    matchLoc = maxLoc;
    std::cout << "Max correlation=" << maxVal << std::endl;
    if(maxVal < 0.8) {
      break;
    }

    /// Show me what you got
    cv::rectangle(img_display, matchLoc, cv::Point(matchLoc.x + templateImg.cols , matchLoc.y + templateImg.rows),
        cv::Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0);
    cv::rectangle(result, cv::Point(matchLoc.x - templateImg.cols/2 , matchLoc.y - templateImg.rows/2),
        cv::Point(matchLoc.x + templateImg.cols/2 , matchLoc.y + templateImg.rows/2 ), cv::Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0);

    cv::imshow("result", result);
    cv::waitKey(0);

    /// Fill the detected location with a rectangle of zero
    cv::rectangle(result, cv::Point( matchLoc.x - templateImg.cols/2 , matchLoc.y - templateImg.rows/2),
        cv::Point(matchLoc.x + templateImg.cols/2 , matchLoc.y + templateImg.rows/2 ), cv::Scalar::all(0), -1);
  } while (maxVal > 0.9);


  cv::imshow("result", result);
  cv::imshow("img_display", img_display);
  cv::waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

The for loop is responsible to find more than one marker and detect it, I am trying to adapt it to my java code and I am getting an infinite loop here is my code:

```
public void run(String inFile, String templateFile, String outFile, int match_method) {
        System.out.println("\nRunning Template Matching");


    Mat img = Highgui.imread(inFile);
    Mat templ = Highgui.imread(templateFile);

    // / Create the result matrix
    int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
    Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    // / Do the Matching and Normalize
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
    Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

    Point matchLoc;
    Point maxLoc;
    Point minLoc;

    MinMaxLocResult mmr;

    boolean iterate = true;
    while(iterate){

    // / Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
    mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
    matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;


    if(mmr.maxVal < 0.8)
    {
        iterate = false;
    }



    // / Show me what you got
    Core.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));

    }

    // Save the visualized detection.
    System.out.println("Writing "+ outFile);
    Highgui.imwrite(outFile, img);

}
```

I notice that the function minMaxLoc has more arguments in c++ than in java, maybe that's the problem? Why I can't get the same behaviour in java can someone help me?

Thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As cyriel said, **You forgot to fill zeros for the maximum location** and hence you got the infinite loop. May be he forgot to explain you that,

```
   for each iteration
   find the max location
   check if max value is greater than desired threshold
   if true 
   show me what is max
   else
   break // not found anything that matches
   make the existing max to be zero and continue to search for other max// you forgot this and hence infinite loop
   end
```

For more insight to the problem,
you can comment the following lines in the c++ code and run it, you will experience similar problem. (Here **cv::Scalar::all(0),-1** args says **fill** the existing max/found region with 0 and continue)

```
// Fill the detected location with a rectangle of zero
    cv::rectangle(result, cv::Point(matchLoc.x - templateImg.cols / 2, matchLoc.y - templateImg.rows / 2),
        cv::Point(matchLoc.x + templateImg.cols / 2, matchLoc.y + templateImg.rows / 2), cv::Scalar::all(0), -1);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helped a lot, I changed the code I had in java and now is working, here it is: http://pastebin.com/HXP9JaMN
Thank you so much ! ;)

Comment: I notice that the template match doesn't work to detect my black squares, I will need to go with @RobAu solution...

Comment: That's fine. Your question seems more towards solving the issue of infinite loop with title Opencv C++ to Java - Template match. You can search here in stackoverflow for more questions related to template match or finding squares or objects in images.

Comment: @DarkLink You might want to actually accept the answer if it solved your original problem.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to draw second rectangle. Original code:

```
 cv::rectangle(result, cv::Point(matchLoc.x - templateImg.cols/2 , matchLoc.y - templateImg.rows/2),
    cv::Point(matchLoc.x + templateImg.cols/2 , matchLoc.y + templateImg.rows/2 ), cv::Scalar::all(0), 2, 8, 0);

...

/// Fill the detected location with a rectangle of zero
cv::rectangle(result, cv::Point( matchLoc.x - templateImg.cols/2 , matchLoc.y - templateImg.rows/2),
    cv::Point(matchLoc.x + templateImg.cols/2 , matchLoc.y + templateImg.rows/2 ), cv::Scalar::all(0), -1);
```

however in your code there is only this:

```
Core.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
        matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
```

The second part of original code most likely is crucial - it draws filled, not just a shape like first line.

Btw this line `Core.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(), matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));` is probably wrong as well - 1) You should draw rectangle on `result` mat, not on `img` mat. 2) In original code there is `Core.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(), matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));` and in your code `new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(), matchLoc.y + templ.rows())`. Are you sure it is fine?

Comment: No the problem is not the second rectangle, actually I dont need it. The problem is on the while(iteration) that doesn't end, I am getting a infinite loop I guess. I tryed to copy the loop from the c++ code but maybe something is left, do you know what?

Answer (score 1):

Although it might help, you don't need `OpenCV` / `JavaCV` for this relatively easy task.

Basically, you want to find regions in you image that are:

```
a: all black
b: square
c: a percentage of size of the total image
```

First, threshold the image so all pixels are either black or white.

My approach would be to find the connected components by scanning the image pixel by pixel until you reach a black pixel. Then 'flood fill' until you have all the black pixels collected. Mark them (color them differently) and store them in some structure (list of points) and repeat until you reached the last pixel of the image.

For each component:

- determine the bounding box (min and max x and y values).
- Calculate
  the size of the box and determine if it is small / large enough
- Calculate the percentage of matching pixels in that box. If it is
  close to 100%, you have a square shape.

You can plot the matching bounding boxes back into your original image.

Comment: I notice that the template match can't detect my black squares, I need to use this solution, but I didn't understood it very well.... you mean check every pixel of the image? won't that take much time? Can you give me some code? thank you very much. I already have the image threshold, all the pixels are black or white

Comment: I'm not going to code your solution, use google to find the algorithms. I once wrote something like this on an Pentium III and still was able to do 30fps. It mainly depends on the resolution of the image.

Comment: Okay just explain me one thing: when I start doing flood fill on the first black pixel, the fill will only work to the connected black pixels right? same component? so I can divide all the black components on image into a list ?

Comment: Yes you get a list of connected components. Then follow the 'for each component' step